# Can't get checked status in iCheck-helper checkbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I use Bootstrap theme in my MVC 4 web application. There is a checkbox in my application.

My Razor code below.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="checkbox">
           <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NeedsRepacking)Needs Repacking
           </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

but there is no check box render in the web browser. Please see the rendered code.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="">
             <div class="icheckbox_minimal-blue" style="position: relative;"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The NeedsRepacking field is required." id="NeedsRepacking" name="NeedsRepacking" type="checkbox" value="true" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins></div><input name="NeedsRepacking" type="hidden" value="false">Needs Repacking
         </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

When I checked the checkbox div class is changed to `icheckbox_minimal-blue checked` .

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="">
             <div class="icheckbox_minimal-blue checked" style="position: relative;"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The NeedsRepacking field is required." id="NeedsRepacking" name="NeedsRepacking" type="checkbox" value="true" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins></div><input name="NeedsRepacking" type="hidden" value="false">Needs Repacking
         </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

But I can't get the checked status of the checkbox.

Comment: Are you using a custom method here?  The default `CheckBoxFor` method does not generate that markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a copy/paste/modify from a project that I am working on and had the same issue with the iCheck library. This solution is not 100% tested so you will need to modify it to your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".checkbox > .icheckbox_minimal-blue > .iCheck-helper").click(function (e) {
            var id = e.toElement.parentNode.firstChild.id;

            var isChecked = $('#' + id).is(':checked');
            if (isChecked)
            {
                alert('Checked!');
            }
    });
</script>
```

N.B. this code can and should be re-factored as well as optimized.